# What information about the Facebook user does the Facebook API allow you?

Tags: facebook

Their wall and their posts to other friends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's largely based on what the user allows you to see. You would at most get access to the [User table](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User_(FQL)) and the [standard user info table](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Standard_user_info_(FQL)). You should also look at the [Users.getInfo() method](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.getInfo)

Comment: So, if the user allows me to see their "stream" or "wall posts", the application can?

Comment: If the user adds your application then you can see everything he allows applications to see, else you will be only able to see his public information (things you see when you visit someones profile and he's not your friend).

Comment: Aye, remember that a user can allow your app to get access and then reduce it's access over time. (bit by bit)

Answer (score 2):

You can get a treasure of information, depending on the permissions your users grant you (as was mention in a previous answer).

You can get a pretty good idea of what you can do from this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0):

The Following link guide you who you can do with facebook user(me) whole information is there if you now about the PHP SDK or any other SDK provided by facebook.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/